# Canvas image different size in pixels from desktop to mobile

Tags: canvas, size, png, viewport, html2canvas

Hey so I've made this site: http://dst.dstealth.com to help automatically generate png images from HTML div elements using html2canvas. My html2canvas is initialized with static width n height.

Now when I use the website on a desktop browser like chrome, it generates and saves the image at a size of 876 x 434 pixels which is my desired output.

BUT when I do the exact same thing on my Android chrome browser it generates an image that is over 2000 x 2000 pixels.

I thought setting a viewport meta would help but that instead made my desktop browser start saving the image in slightly larger resolutions instead so I've commented that out in my code for now.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here and how I can ensure that the image generated will ALWAYS be 876 x 434?

Comment: According to the html2canvas documentation, you need to set the scale property to 1 so it doesn't use the devicePixelRatio: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

Comment: so i've added the scale option to my html2canvas call and it hasnt seem to change anything... `html2canvas(box, {width: WD, height: HT, scale: 1}).then(function(canvas) {`

Also side note, I was curious what my device's devicePixelRatio was so I added a field in my html to display the device pixel ratio and on my desktop the value shows as `1` on my browser, but on my mobile it doesn't return a value at all... is that normal? :/

Comment: turns out was just a caching issue on my phone, once the cache was cleared that did the trick! plz post as answer so I can nominate as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the html2canvas documentation, you need to set the scale property to 1 so it doesn't use the devicePixelRatio: [html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration)