# CSS set element size in real pixels, not device pixel

Tags: html, css

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#a")).then(function(canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function(aBlob) {
      var a = document.createElement('a'),
        b = URL.createObjectURL(aBlob);
      a.setAttribute('download', 'captured_image.png');
      a.setAttribute('href', b);
      a.click();
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="a" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red;">
  This is 100px div
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.0/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

(Because of cross origin it will not work on stackoverflow but in localhost it works but if you use hi-res display downloaded image will be 200px not 100px)
```

I am generating "screenshot" of page displayed in iframe and I always want it to be fixed size 100x100 pixels. It works on my PC but when I run the code at high resolution computers, downloaded image is bigger than 100x100 (e.g. 200x200). I think it's because of the device pixels are bigger, but how can I set it to be in pixels? My current code is:

```
iframe {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Is it possible to ignore device pixels and force to use normal pixels?

Edit: working solution by JHeth comment below: html2canvas(element, {scale:1}).then(...)

Comment: I think we'll need more info here. How are you creating the screenshot?

Comment: html2canvas, in the iframe I just make screenshot of whole page and download it

Comment: Could you put an example into your question see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: added demo snippet

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825013/canvas-image-different-size-in-pixels-from-desktop-to-mobile

Comment: Yes, it works. html2canvas(element, {scale:1}).then(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html2canvas(element, {scale:1}).then(...)